# Module not found: Can't resolve 'pg-hstore'

Tags: next.js, sequelize.js, next-auth

> Import trace for requested module:
> ./node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/postgres/data-types.js
> ./node_modules/sequelize/lib/data-types.js
> ./node_modules/sequelize/lib/sequelize.js
> ./node_modules/sequelize/lib/index.js
> ./utils/database.js
> ./utils/models/User.js
> ./utils/dbfunctions/UserFunctions.js
> ./auth.config.js
> ./middleware.js
> ./node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/postgres/hstore.js:2:15
> Module not found: Can't resolve 'pg-hstore'
>
> https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/module-not-found
>
> Import trace for requested module:
> ./node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/postgres/data-types.js
> ./node_modules/sequelize/lib/data-types.js
> ./node_modules/sequelize/lib/sequelize.js
> ./node_modules/sequelize/lib/index.js
> ./utils/database.js
> ./utils/models/User.js
> ./auth.config.js
> ./middleware.js

I am getting this error only when I am using this getUserByEmail function.

auth.config.js

```
import Credentials from "next-auth/providers/credentials";
import { LoginSchema } from "@/schemas";
import { getUserByEmail } from "@/utils/dbfunctions/UserFunctions";

export default {
  providers: [
    Credentials({
      async authorize(credentials) {
        const validatedFields = LoginSchema.safeParse(credentials);

        if (validatedFields.success) {
          const { email, password } = validatedFields.data;

          const user = await getUserByEmail(email);

          if (!user || !user.password) return null;

          const passwordMatch = password === user.password;

          if (passwordMatch) return user;
        }

        return null;
      },
    }),
  ],
};
```

auth.js

```
import NextAuth from "next-auth";
import authConfig from "./auth.config";
import SequelizeAdapter from "@auth/sequelize-adapter";
import sequelize from "./utils/database";

export const {
  handlers: { GET, POST },
  auth,
  signIn,
  signOut,
} = NextAuth({
  adapter: SequelizeAdapter(sequelize),
  session: { strategy: "jwt" },
  ...authConfig,
});
```

UserFunctions.js

```
import { Op } from "sequelize";
import User from "../models/User";

export const getUserByEmail = async (email) => {
  try {
    const user = await User.findOne({ where: email, is_delete: 0 });

    return user;
  } catch {
    return null;
  }
};
```

database.js

```
const { Sequelize } = require("sequelize");

const db_host = process.env.DB_HOST;
const db_user = process.env.DB_USER;
const db_pass = process.env.DB_PASS;
const db_default = process.env.DB_DEFAULT;

const sequelize = new Sequelize({
  host: db_host,
  username: db_user,
  password: db_pass,
  database: db_default,
  dialect: "mysql",
  dialectModule: require("mysql2"),
  benchmark: true,
  type: "mysql",
});

export default sequelize;
```

middleware.js

```
// import { auth } from "./auth";
import NextAuth from "next-auth";
import authConfig from "@/auth.config";
import {
  DEFAULT_LOGIN_REDIRECT,
  apiAuthPrefix,
  authRoutes,
  publicRoutes,
} from "@/routes";

const { auth } = NextAuth(authConfig);

export default auth((req) => {
  const { nextUrl } = req;
  const isLoggedIn = !!req.auth;
  // console.log("Route: ", req.nextUrl.pathname);
  // console.log("isLoggedIn: ", isLoggedIn);

  const isApiAuthRoute = nextUrl.pathname.startsWith(apiAuthPrefix);
  const isPublicRoute = publicRoutes.includes(nextUrl.pathname);
  const isAuthRoute = authRoutes.includes(nextUrl.pathname);

  if (isApiAuthRoute) {
    return null;
  }

  if (isAuthRoute) {
    if (isLoggedIn) {
      return Response.redirect(new URL(DEFAULT_LOGIN_REDIRECT, nextUrl));
    }

    return null;
  }

  if (!isLoggedIn && !isPublicRoute) {
    return Response.redirect(new URL("/auth/login", nextUrl));
  }

  return null;
});

export const config = {
  matcher: ["/((?!.+\\.[\\w]+$|_next).*)", "/", "/(api|trpc)(.*)"],
};
```